# How to change animation direction on CSS expanding button

Tags: css

I have a round CSS Button floating at the left bottom corner of the webpage that at the moment expands with text to the right/center of the fixed position .. I have been struggling with how I can change this so that it expand the text to the left of the button, and so that the initial button's (round) right side simply just not move.. Can anyone help me out? :-)

The Code I have:

```css
#container-floating {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 260px;
  z-index: 50px;
}


/* Effect 1: Brackets */

.cc-rockmenu {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 26px;
  background: #004d6f;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 3px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) !important;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling:hover {
  width: 312px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon {
  float: left;
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52px;
  background: #004d6f;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px 8px 3px 10px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon:hover .rolling {
  width: 312px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling i.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-face: Helvetica;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a {
  color: #FFFFFFF;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a:before {
  content: "\00bb";
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling p {
  margin: 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling input[type="text"] {
  width: 175px;
  background: #bbae79 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling input[type="submit"] {
  background: #004d6f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px;
}


/* Rolling Animated Menu*/

.rollingAnimated ul {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 44%;
}

.rollingAnimated ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
}

.rollingAnimated a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1.4) 0s;
}

.rollingAnimated a:hover {
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-floating">
  <section align="">
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="colum_full column">
            <div class="cc-rockmenu">
              <div class="rolling">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ReportIssueModal">
                  <figure class="rolling_icon"><img src="https://efp.i-r.dk/img/megaphone.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;" border="0"></figure>
                  <span><font style="color: #FFFFFF;">Report Problem</font><br><font style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;"><i>Some text here!</i></font></span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `text-align:center` from `.cc-rockmenu`

Comment: Hi Pete .. yes that fix it to its position, but it does not change so that the text expand to the left and not the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the direction of your animation by doing the following:

- remove the width from your container
- change text align to right on cc-rockmenu
- remove the dimensions and float from your rolling_icon
- make the link flex with a direction of row reverse

```css
#container-floating {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 260px;
  z-index: 50px;
}


/* Effect 1: Brackets */

.cc-rockmenu {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 26px;
  background: #004d6f;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 3px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) !important;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling:hover {
  width: 312px;
}

.rolling-link {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon {
  z-index: 9;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #004d6f;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px 8px 3px 10px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling .rolling_icon:hover .rolling {
  width: 312px;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling i.fa {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-face: Helvetica;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a {
  color: #FFFFFFF;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling li a:before {
  content: "\00bb";
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling p {
  margin: 0;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling input[type="text"] {
  width: 175px;
  background: #bbae79 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.cc-rockmenu .rolling input[type="submit"] {
  background: #004d6f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px;
}


/* Rolling Animated Menu*/

.rollingAnimated ul {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 44%;
}

.rollingAnimated ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0 25px 0 0;
}

.rollingAnimated a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 1.4) 0s;
}

.rollingAnimated a:hover {
  margin-top: -65px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-floating">
  <section align="">
    <div class="rt-container">
      <div class="col-rt-12">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="colum_full column">
            <div class="cc-rockmenu">
              <div class="rolling">
                <a class="rolling-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ReportIssueModal">
                  <figure class="rolling_icon"><img src="https://efp.i-r.dk/img/megaphone.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;" border="0"></figure>
                  <span><font style="color: #FFFFFF;">Report Problem</font><br><font style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 12px;"><i>Some text here!</i></font></span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```